# How to deal with package.json "homepage" attribute and api endpoints

Tags: reactjs, proxy, http-status-code-302

I'm trying to migrate an angularjs project to React (from scratch), and I'm facing to a strange issue when calling the first endpoint that should returns a specific configuration.

For some reasons, I had to add   "homepage": "/front-react" in my package.json. So the angularJS app run in root directory, and we can access to the react app from /front-react (there is more backend conf that i can't show, but that's the idea). This thing works, no problem with it.

I'm using "createApi" RTK Query to make queries, this looks like this :

```
export const loginApi = createApi({
  reducerPath: 'loginApi',
  baseQuery: fetchBaseQuery({
    baseUrl: '/',
    headers: {
      pragma: 'no-cache',
      Accept: 'application/json',
    },
  }),
  endpoints: (builder) => ({
    getConfiguration: builder.query<any, void>({
      query: () => ({
        url: `/rest-api/public/configuration`,
      }),
    }),
  }),
});
```

now in my login page, I just did this :

```
const { data: configuration} = useGetConfigurationQuery();
```

And this is where things become weird.

first, I got a 200 status, but the response was my index.html.

I tried to add the header Accept: application/json, and now I got a 302 status, followed by a 404.
The 302 trigger another api call with "/front-react" before the endpoint so it looks like "/front-react/rest-api/public/configuration" instead of "/rest-api/public/configuration" (this is why i got a 404).

I tried to add a setupProxy.js using http-proxy-middleware, but nothing better.

I have no idea what to do next, I don't know if I'm missing configuration in react.

Thanks for reading

(I tried on postman and the endpoint works fine)